# $Length-attribute output

Tags: fields-attributes, qgis-3, length

I created a layer to visualize cable-laying and want to export the sum of the cable-lengths to an excel file when I'm done so i created an attribute for it.

How do I link an attribute to the auto-calculated $length?

I am using QGIS 3.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added an attribute with the open-field-calculator and was able to set the formula round($length,2) to get the length as an output.

Adding it through the layer-properties didn't save the formula and just set the length for already existing attributes.
Now every new added attribute automatically gets a length-value.